# Why doesn't Flow understand that nullable properties are compatible with non-nullable object properties?

Tags: javascript, flowtype, refinement-type

I'm trying to understand why flow is complaining about incompatibility between the properties of two very similar objects ([try-flow-example](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoALgTwA4FMwDCiYAvGAN6phgB2AhgLa4BcYA-AM7oBOAljQHNUAXypgMOfADlGuACZEkZStXpNWXPoJGpUUAK40Axul5waYKHDhgAFEdaKAlBp78BFMbyh2jAOjV8EjIafRgYJzBuXHR9bgsAcjoac0wGOH0OBLFo2Piwf0CdVCNzLjBcGA46VhkmBWJlWllWBIBRKroEsFE9a1tK6qcgA)):

```
/* @flow */
type Cow = {
  name: ?string
}

type NamedCow = {
  name: string
}

function foo (c: Cow): string {
  if (c.name == null) return 'anonymous'
  return c.name
}

const elsa: NamedCow = { name: 'Elsa' }

foo(elsa)
```

Flow gives the following error with the above code:

```
17: foo(elsa)
        ^ NamedCow. This type is incompatible with the expected param type of
10: function foo (c: Cow): string {
                     ^ Cow
    Property `name` is incompatible:
        7:   name: string
                   ^ string. This type is incompatible with
        3:   name: ?string
                   ^ null or undefined
```

Why is the more specific `name: string` incompatible with the less specific `name: ?string`?  Wouldn't `NamedCow` be covariant to `Cow` over the name property since the name property of `NamedCow` is a sub-set of the name property of Cow?

Relevant docs:
[Flow docs on subtypes](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/subtypes/#toc-subtypes-of-objects)

Answer (score 2):

Object types are invariant. This is due to the fact that object properties can be read and written.

To see why covariance is unsafe, consider a function that assigns `null` to the property `name` in the `foo` function.

Passing a `Cow` type: assignment to `name = null` poses no issue since `name` can be `?string`.

But, if you pass a `NamedCow` type, the assignment to `name = null` would violate the type for `name` which is only `string`.

---

You can annotate `name` to be covariant by prefixing it with `+`, that is `+name: ?string`. This indicates that no writes will be performed on it. That should clear away the errors you're currently seeing. (The property variance modifiers are [somewhat hidden in the docs](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/interfaces/#toc-interface-property-variance-read-only-and-write-only))

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

The docs seem to infer that the the variance modifiers only apply to interfaces, is this the case? 

Also, I found the single line in the docs where object property invariance is mentioned, wish it was more prominently explained or at least explained in the variance section:
    [By default, object properties are invariant, which allow both reads and writes, but are more restrictive in the values they accept.](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/depth-subtyping/)

Comment: The variance modifiers will apply to object types as seen [here (try-flow)](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoALgTwA4FMwDCiYAvGAN6phgDUAdgIYC2uAXGAPwDO6ATgJZ0A5qgC+VMBhz4Acs1wATIkjKVqjFux4DhY1KigBXOgGN0-OHTBQ4cMAAoT7ZQEotfQUIoT+UByYA6DXwSMjpDGBgXMF5cdENeKwByBjpLTCY4Qy4kiVj4xLBA4L1UE0seMFwYLgZ2ORYlYlUwYPYkgFEahiSwcQNbe2ralyA)